# How to return duration soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using.

```
function item_duration(link,name) {
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: ''+name+'',
        url: ''+link+'',
        volume: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        onload: function(){ 
            if (this.readyState == 3) {
                return this.duration;
            }
        }
    });
    //sound_duration.load();
    //sound_duration.stop();
   // soundManager.unload(''+name+'');
}
```

But it is not returning the duration it gives me 0, i tried to alert the duration and there is not 0 the alert shows different, but it takes time before the alert appear.I don't thing that is the problem because i have statement .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the duration by simply accessing the duration attribute of SoundManager object.

```
  function getDuration()
  {
    var soundFile = {};
    soundFile.id = 'aSound';
    soundFile.url = '/tech/js/sound/s.mp3';
    var mySound = soundManager.createSound(soundFile);
    return mySound.duration;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
soundManger.play('idSound',{
     whileplaying: function(){
         console.log(this.duration);
     }
});
```